# When window scroll, I want to append a div and hide the div when scroll back to top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a function, when user scroll down to the middle, the menu will have a class 'sticky', when the div has class 'sticky', I want to append a div. The issue is that it will keep append the div when I scroll. Second issue is that, when I scroll back to the top, the the append sticky stay. help, appreciate.

```js
 jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
     
     if(jQuery('.main-menu-top').hasClass('sticky')){
      jQuery('.main-menu-top').append('<div id="checkout_sticky"></div>');
          }else{
            /*I want to hide the checkout_sticky, try hide(), doesn't work*/
   });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create something that changes once complete. To do so,

create a var with the value of true, and then in your if statement check if it is true, if so run function and then in that function change the value of the var to false.

```
var test = true;

jQuery(window).scroll(function(){

           if(jQuery('.main-menu-top').hasClass('sticky') && test==true){
test = false;
               jQuery('.main-menu-top').append('<div id="checkout_sticky"></div>');
                   }else{
            /*I want to hide the checkout_sticky, try hide(), doesn't work*/
   });
```

To make it hide, you could try;

```
else { 
    $('#checkout_sticky').css("visibility","hidden");  
}
```

If that doesn't work you can try,

```
$('#checkout_sticky').removeAttr('id');
```

Comment: $('#checkout_sticky').css("visibility","hidden");  and removeAttr doesn't work.

Comment: @conan can I ask what are you gaining from .appending is it just the id? or is there more code that fills in the div?

Comment: it is just the id that I append. If I use removeAttr id, nothing will show when i scroll down.

Comment: @conan so it removes it but you want it to come back when scrolling back down?

Comment: @conan Ohh... in the else statement add test = true;

Comment: @conan you could also try  jQuery('.main-menu-top').html(''); however that will remove everything in the .main-menu-top

Comment: If I add  test = true; in the else statement, it improve, when I scroll down, it flash once, then disappear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80612/discussion-between-matthew-hammond-and-conan).

Comment: @conan can you send more some more of your code so I can play around with it, i have opened at a chat so you can upload the files if needed

Comment: Very appreciate that, I add .length !==0 in the else statement, it works fine now. You are the first guy on stackoverflow will go that far to help me. really appreicate. If  Matthew Hammond is your real name, I will remember you. I am creating a online t-shirt store, if I could make money, I definitely mail you back today's consulting fees.

Comment: @conan its cool man, I'm learning at the same time so by trying to help you I learn new things, I didn't know about the .length either, I had to post a question, as far as I got on my own was some crazy flickering. If you need anymore help let me know and I will try!

Comment: @conan Feel free to send me a link to your t-shirts, i need to buy a few more ;)

Comment: Thanks, sayhitoworld.com is the link. I still need two more days to finish it. If you could tell more friend about it, i appreciate.